# I am getting this error in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

When I retrieve more than 200 000 records from server to clients I am getting this error:

> The underlying connection was closed:
>   A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - are you opening a connection for each DB request or keeping one alive for a long time and re-using it?

Comment: without seeing your code this would be more like guess for us but here is an idea.. if you are creating any connections with the `using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection)) {}` for example the connection gets disposed if you try accessing the sqlConn object when out of scope and the connection is not global it will be closed etc.. try showing us the code where the actual issue is occurring meaning you need to set up breakpoints and step through the code using the debugger...

Answer (score 0):

Many things can lead to this issue in WCF. The best way to solve is definetly to add trace log. Add the following code to your configuration file to active the tracing :

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="e:\path_tolog\WebTrace.svclog"  /> <-- Path to the log file 
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, without seeing any code, we can only guess, but I have seen similar problems when trying to send an unenumerated query across WCF.

For example, if you have something like (Warning: Air code!) this..

```
var data = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.CustType == 1);
```

...and you try and return this from a WCF service method, you'll get the exception you mentioned. This is because the query is set up, and sent out to WCF where it is serialised, which fails as the serialisation attempts to enumerate the query after the connection has been closed.

The answer is to force enumeration of the query before you return it. You can do this by adding .ToList() to the end of the query (amongst other ways).

As I said, without seeing any code this is a complete guess, but I ahve had the same exception in these circumstances, so it's worth checking.